# Why the selected rows don't stay selected after scrolling in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-14.2-defect

Why the selected rows become unselected if the list is scrolled (See the pictures)? Xcode 12.2. iOS 14.2.

I also get a console message:

> [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view
> while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is
> not allowed.

**Update**

This seems to be iOS 14.2 bug. I downloaded a simulator for iOS 14.1 version and everything works just fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedRows = Set<String>()
    var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4","item5","item6","item7","item8","item9","item10","item11","item12","item13","item14","item15","item16","item17","item18","item19","item20","item21","item22"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedRows) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(.active))
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Select cells]
[image: Scroll the list up]
[image: Scroll the list down]

Comment: Works fine with 14.1. I assume you use 14.2, right?

Comment: Yes. iOS version is 14.2.

Comment: Thanks for the testing. I can confirm that in iOS 14.1 there is no problem.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior on 14.5 in the iPad simulator as well.